# Availability of ZoneIds on other platforms

Tags: java, java-time

Getting the ZoneId via the `of("...")` methods requires a String with the specific id. The available ids can be retrieved using `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`. Which will return (at least on my system and JDK) a long list of 589 ids. Are those guaranteed to be available on any JDK8 implementation/platform? How about android and eg. OpenJDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zone ids are taken from the [Time Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), which is updated regularly.

Each version of Java is linked to a specific version of that database - see for example [the release notes of 8u77](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u77-relnotes-2944725.html):

> JDK 8u77 contains IANA time zone data version 2016a

You can see more details about the changes for each version on [Timezone Data Versions in the JRE Software](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html).

So is it not guaranteed that the IDs you see will be available on a previous update of the JDK 8 (I suspect they don't get deleted and so would probably be available in subsequent versions - TBC).

Comment: Oracle provides a [Timezone Updater Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html) to install fresh zone info into an Oracle JDK or JRE.